# mysqldump command is not executed just it is saved on a file

Tags: php, mysql, backup

I am coding a php script for backup a database, the idea is to use mysqldump command and then download a sql file with the result, unfortunately the output of the mysqldump is not save on the file, just the source code. This is the code:

```php
    $archivo = 'bkbiblioteca_' . date("d-m-Y_H:i:s") . '.sql';      
    $comando = "mysqldump --add-drop-table --host=$servidor --user=$usuario --password=$clave $base > $archivo";
    try{
        $archivo_manejador = fopen($archivo, 'w+');
        fwrite($archivo_manejador, $comando);
        fclose($archivo_manejador);
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($archivo));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($archivo));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($archivo);
        unlink($archivo);      
      }catch(\Exception $e){
        echo 'error en el proceso de bk' . $e->getMessage(); //TODO: favor incluir en la bitacora global del sistema
      }//fin de catch
```

Right now I am getting the file with this line:
mysqldump --add-drop-table --host=$servidor --user=$usuario --password=$clave $base > $archivo

I have tried with this command:

```php
system("$comando");
```

But it does not work, so I can't not figure out how to execute the mysqldump command and obtain the result in the file instead of get the source code line.

Thanks in advance

Comment: At the moment, you're just writing `$comando` to `$archivo`. Try the system call, and remove the `$archivo_manejador` lines, then check the contents of `$archivo`

Comment: what do you get with echo exec("$comando") ? Are you executing your PHP script from CLI ?

Comment: Comment the line $archivo_manejador = fopen($archivo, 'w+') solved the problem, now I am getting the needed output. Merci Francois

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `--result-file` option of `mysqldump` to create the dump file which you may then send to the browser for download. The full command would be (insert your file names as desired):

```
exec('mysqldump --user=backup --password="yourpasswordhere#" --routines --insert-ignore --complete-insert --force --result-file=name_of_your_dump_file_here.sql --databases ' . $yourdatabasename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting this line solve the problem:

```php
$archivo_manejador = fopen($archivo, 'w+');
```

Now I am getting the needed output. Thanks to Francois Huppé for the comment.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
system($comando);
```

Or maybe:

```
exec($comando);
```

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference. The double quotes interprets the variable.